# How to Alter Table from SparkSQL based on the DataFrame without dropping the hive table, like drop/add columns?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am Trying to Alter a Hive Table using Spark, like adding columns or dropping columns from the Hive table based on the Spark DataFrame output. Below is what I tried, kind of a huge code,

```
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("SchemaHandle")
      .enableHiveSupport
      .getOrCreate

    //Assume below is my generated DataFrame
    import spark.implicits._
    val dfSample = Seq(
      (12, "Dallas", "Texas", 55, "BOOK S","hello","Hellotwo"),
      (12, "SF", "CA", 25, "RULER","hello","Hellotwo"),
      (13, "NYC", "NY", 53, "PENCIL S","hello","Hellotwo"),
      (14, "Miami", "Fl", 45, "RULER","hello","Hellotwo"),
      (12, "Houston", "Texas", 75, "MARKER","hello","Hellotwo"),
      (11, "jersey", "NJ", 53, "WHITE NE R","hello","Hellotwo"),
      (19, "new orleans", "LO", 45, "HIGHLIGHTNER","hello","Hellotwo")
    ).toDF("id", "city", "state", "qty", "item","columnone","columntwo")

    try {
      spark.sql("truncate table database.schematest")
      println("Successfully truncated database.schematest")
    } catch {
      case _: Throwable => println("This Job is running for the very first time, so no table to truncate - We'll create the table below")
        dfSample.write.format("parquet").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable(s"database.schematest")
        println("Output Table Saved to database.schematest")
    }

    //Assume this is Spark DF Schema.
    val seqone: Seq[StructField] = dfSample.schema
    //Assume this is Existing Table Schema.
    val seqtwo: Seq[StructField] = spark.table("database.schematest").schema

    //Get Cols- with Schema to be Added
    val diffedSeq = seqone diff seqtwo
    //Get Cols- with Schema to be Dropped
    val diffedSeqTwo = seqtwo diff seqone

    //Get Cols- names to just make the diff
    val seqonecolumns = dfSample.columns

    //Get Cols- names to just make the diff
    val seqtwocolumns = spark.table("dscoewrk_ing_qa.schematest").columns

    val diffedSeqArrayOne = seqonecolumns diff seqtwocolumns

    val diffedSeqArrayTwo = seqtwocolumns diff seqonecolumns

    var fixedAlterColumns: String = ""
    for (i <- diffedSeqArrayOne) {
      for (j <- diffedSeq) {
        if (i.equals(j.name)) {
          fixedAlterColumns +=""+j.name +" "+ datatypeCheckFunction(j.dataType.toString)+","
        }
      }
    }
    if(fixedAlterColumns.length>0) {
      println(s"Result---> ${fixedAlterColumns.substring(0, fixedAlterColumns.length - 1)}")
      //Lets add new columns to table database.schematest.
      spark.sql(s"ALTER TABLE database.schematest ADD COLUMNS (${fixedAlterColumns.substring(0, fixedAlterColumns.length - 1)})")
      println("Alter Table Success")
    }else{
      println("No Columns to Add")
    }

    println("------------------------------BREAK---------------------------")

    //Now lets think about dropping the columns
    val dfSampleCurrentTable:Seq[StructField] = spark.table("dscoewrk_ing_qa.schematest").schema
    //Since we cannot drop columns from Hive Table, lets do REPLACE COLUMNS.
    val dfSampleFinalDiff = dfSampleCurrentTable diff diffedSeqTwo
    dfSampleFinalDiff.foreach(println)
    val dfSampleFinalDiffColArray = (spark.table("database.schematest").columns) diff diffedSeqArrayTwo
    dfSampleFinalDiffColArray.foreach(println)
    var fixedDropColumns:String = ""

    for(i <- dfSampleFinalDiffColArray){
      println("The i is"+i)
      for(j <-dfSampleCurrentTable){
        println("This is j"+j)
        if(i.equals(j.name)){
          fixedDropColumns+=""+j.name +" "+ datatypeCheckFunction(j.dataType.toString)+","
        }
      }
    }
    //Let's drop the columns that aren't required.

    if(fixedDropColumns.length>0) {
      println(s"Result---> ${fixedDropColumns.substring(0, fixedDropColumns.length - 1)}")
      spark.sql(s"ALTER TABLE database.schematest REPLACE COLUMNS(${fixedDropColumns.substring(0,fixedDropColumns.length-1)})")
      println("Alter Drop Table Success")
    }else{
      println("No Columns to Drop")
    }

    //Now let's save the DF to Output in the Table. By using Append as below.
    dfSample.withColumn("mybool",functions.lit(null)).coalesce(50).write.format("parquet").mode(SaveMode.Append).insertInto("database.schematest")

    println("Saving output Table Successful.")

  }

   def datatypeCheckFunction(datatypePassed: String): String = {
    datatypePassed match {
      case "BinaryType" | "ByteType" | "DateType" | "NullType" | "StringType" | "TimestampType" => "String"
      case "BooleanType" => "boolean"
      case "DoubleType" | "FloatType" => "Double"
      case "IntegerType" | "ShortType" => "Int"
      case "LongType" => "BigInt"
      case _ => "String"
    }
  }
}
```

I can understand that there is room for optimization but atleast for this code, I see two issues:
 1. When I run the above Spark job, Add columns is successfull but the REPLACE columns is failing with below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
Operation not allowed: ALTER TABLE REPLACE COLUMNS(line 1, pos 0)

== SQL ==
ALTER TABLE database.schematest REPLACE COLUMNS(id Int,city String,state String,qty Int,item String,columnone String,columntwo String)
```

2. Assume REPLACE Columns has worked, will it also delete the data for that dropping column?

Here is my Hive Create Table Statement used:

```
create table schematest(`id` int, `city` string, `state` string, `qty` int, `mybool` boolean) stored as parquet
```

Any help is appreciated, Thank you All in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this paragraph in [Hive manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Add/ReplaceColumns):

> REPLACE COLUMNS removes all existing columns and adds the new set of columns. This can be done only for tables with a native SerDe (DynamicSerDe, MetadataTypedColumnsetSerDe, LazySimpleSerDe and ColumnarSerDe)

It seems that for parquet isn't supported, as I understood.

Comment: Does that mean I can use ORC File Format?